# How to split long python code into multiple code-blocks in org-mode? (indentation)

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, python, tangle

Just starting to learn `org-mode` and `tangle` to write documentation of my Python source codes. I have a several hundred lines long function.

I want to separate this long function into several small code-blocks, and then make explanation what that small parts do. But it seems indentation is not working as expected.

Is it possible to split code into multiple code-blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<<noweb>>` blocks are indented:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC 
def main():
  <<foo>>
#+END_SRC
```

And then

```
#+NAME: foo
#+BEGIN_SRC
print("hello, world")
#+END_SRC
```

Does this help?